# Find or create by field doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Ive got a model caleld SpacialBody, and I need to seed some records so first off I added this to my seeds.rb

```
[
    ["Sol",0,0,0,"standard"]
].each do |body|
    nb=SpacialBody.find_or_create_by_name(body[0])
    nb.name = body[0]
    nb.x = body[1]
    nb.y = body[2]
    nb.type = SpacialBody::Types[body[3]]
    nb.class = body[4]
    nb.save
end
```

and this produced an error. I then went into console to test the code and found that this happened:

> > SpacialBody.new
> >     => #
> >     SpacialBody.find_by_name("Sol")
> >     => nil
> >     SpacialBody.find_or_create_by_name("Sol")
> >     NoMethodError: undefined method `generated_methods' for nil:NilClass
> >         from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:52:in`method_missing'
> >         from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:356:in `respond_to?'
> >         from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2906:in`assign_attributes'
> >         from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2902:in `each'
> >         from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2902:in`assign_attributes'
> >         from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2775:in `attributes='
> >         from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1965:in`send'
> >         from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1965:in `find_or_create_by_name'
> >         from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2475:in`initialize'
> >         from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1963:in `new'
> >         from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1963:in`find_or_create_by_name'
> >         from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1975:in `send'
> >         from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1975:in`method_missing'
> >         from (irb):3

Ive used find_or_create_by_field in other projects without incedent, and i cant see anything different in my setup here.

Its only this model that has the problem, others in the same project work fine.

Comment: Have you checked your model's validations?

Comment: There are no validations the model is just class SpacialBody < ActiveRecord::Base end first thing i did was remove things like the attraccesor line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*facepalm*

using class and type as fields in the model.... not a good move

both are reserved names which cause ActiveRecord to fail when building the methods.